# How can I "decrypt" back according to the terms of this problem

Tags: python, arrays, string

I am learning to program in Python right now and I can't solve one problem.
The main work is time-consuming and I am close to a kind of deadline in my training course. Please help me!

---

Conditions of the problem:
Based on N, the size of the matrix is calculated into which the source text will be packed: the square root is extracted from N, and its lower bound is taken as the number of rows of the matrix, and the upper bound is taken as the number of columns. If their product is less than N, increase the number of lines.

For example, there is a line of text:
"hello boy abstract pizza"

The length of this string is 21, the square root is 4.58.
21 elements are not packed into a 4x5 matrix, so we take a 5x5 matrix:

```
[
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'], 
['b', 'o', 'y', 'a', 'b'], 
['s', 't', 'r', 'a', 'c'], 
['t', 'p', 'i', 'z', 'z'], 
['a']
]
```

And finally, we produce the encrypted result, displaying characters in columns from top to bottom and from left to right, and separating the columns with spaces:

hbsta eotp lyri laaz obcz

Write a code to encrypt the text message and a decoder to decode it.

The function gets the original string "s" and either encrypts it (encode = true) or decrypts it (encode = false), but of course without the original spaces

---

What I have already done is "encryption" part (code below). But I can't figure out how to "decrypt" back.

```
def TheRabbitFoot(s, encode):

    if encode:

        s = s.replace(' ', '')

        s_length = len(s)
        s_sqrt = round((s_length ** 0.5), 2)

        matrix_rows = int(s_sqrt // 1)
        matrix_cols = int(str(s_sqrt)[2:3])

        while matrix_rows * matrix_cols < s_length:
            matrix_rows += 1

        encrypt = []

        while len(s) > matrix_cols:
            encrypt.append(list(s[:matrix_cols]))
            s = s[matrix_cols:]
        else:
            encrypt.append(list(s))

        result = []

        for i in range(matrix_cols):
            for j in range(matrix_rows):
                if i < len(encrypt[j]):
                    result.append(encrypt[j][i])
            result.append(' ')

        result = ''.join(result).strip()

        print(result)

    else:

        ??????????
```

Thanks for answers! Here is a clarification:

I need to code "decrypt" part of function, so to be able to decrypt strings encrypted with same function. In example above we get encrypted string:

```
hbsta eotp lyri laaz obcz
```

and we need to decrypt it back without spaces, so it it should return string like this:

```
helloboyabstractpizza
```

I'm trying to make a 2D list from that string and iterate through columns:

```
else:

    decrypt = s.split()
    result = []

    for i in range(len(decrypt)):
        string = decrypt[i]
        string = list(string)
        decrypt[i] = string

    for i in range(len(decrypt[0]) - 1):
        for j in range(len(decrypt[i])):
            result.append(decrypt[j][i])

    print(''.join(result))
```

but I messed up the indexes and I get:

```
helloboyastratpiz
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def decode(encoded_string):
    if not encoded_string:
        return ''

    # Split the characters at whitespace.
    columns = encoded_string.split()

    characters = []
    index = 0

    # Loop over the columns consuming the characters until
    # we have no more and an IndexError occurs.
    while True:
        for column in columns:
            try:
                character = column[index]
            except IndexError:
                return ''.join(characters)
            characters.append(character)
        index += 1
```

e.g.

```py
decode('hbsta eotp lyri laaz obcz')
>>> 'helloboyabstractpizza'
```

---

**Explanation**

1. First, I split the string into `columns`. For the example case, this is a list like so: `['hbsta', 'eotp', 'lyri', 'laaz', 'obcz']`
2. I define a list `characters` to hold the characters in the decoded order.
3. I define an `index` variable which holds the character offset we are currently looking at.
4. I start a loop that takes the character at the `index` position in each string in the `columns` list and appends it into the `characters` list. So, I take the character in the zero-th position from each string, then increase the index and take the character from the first position in each string, etc.
5. I exit the loop once `index` and points to a character that does not exist in a given `column` string.
6. Once this stopping criteria is met, I join all the characters together with an empty string.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Here the problem - I must decrypt string getting by this algorithm backwards.

Comment: so in example above we have string:
hbsta eotp lyri laaz obcz

and it has to be decrypted to:
helloboyabstractpizza

Comment: I see, I have altered the `decode` function to take the string rather than the matrix input. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Yeah! This works and solve the problem! Many thanks to you)))
if it doesn't bother you, can you explain how it works?

Comment: Great! I edited the answer to provide an explanation. Please accept my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much again. I accepted your answer because your code actually works and solves the problem. But when I upload solution to the validation server, I get a failure.

"Exception when accessing TheRabbitsFoot () in encryption mode" 

it seems that there is some tests that do not allow exceptions 
I'm ruined. I have less than day to solve this problem other way((